# Using loop in CarouselSlider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
        itemCount: broadcasterLength,
        itemBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, int index, int pageViewIndex) {
          for(var i = 0; i < broadcasterLength; i++){
            print('i= $i');
            for (var k = 0; k < liveResult[i].broadcasters!.length; k++){
              print('k $k');
              return InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PictureInPicturePage(broadcastUrl: liveResult[i].broadcasters![k].liveStream!, matchId: liveResult[i].matchId!, profileID: liveResult[i].broadcasters![k].profile!.id!, isReplay: false, sportType: liveResult[i].sports!, ID: liveResult[i].id!,)),
                  );
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        child: Container(
                            height: 120,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                    "assets/img/container/Rectangle.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                      16, 13, 10, 8),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        width: 180,
                                        child: Text(
                                            languageProvider.selectedLanguage == 'en' ? liveResult[i].league!.nameEn!: liveResult[i].league!.nameVi!,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xFFF0D39A),
                                              fontSize: 10,
                                              fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              height: 0,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.81,
                                            ),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/img/container/Live.png',
                                        height: 15,
                                        width: 40,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                      16, 0, 10, 8),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50,
                                            height: 50,
                                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: NetworkImage(
                                                    liveResult[i].broadcasters![k].profile!.avatar!),
                                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              ),
                                              shape: OvalBorder(),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            width: 70,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                  liveResult[i]
                                                      .broadcasters![k]
                                                      .profile!
                                                      .nickname!,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 10,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  ),
                                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                      )),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
          return Container(child: Text('No livestream'),);
        },
        options: CarouselOptions(),
      ),
```

I am using this [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package.
Above are my code on how to loop through the `broadcasterLength` and the `liveResult[i].broadcasters!.length` inside the carousel slider.

How to loop the `broadcasterLength` and the `liveResult[i].broadcasters!.length`? Every time it is loop, it will print out the i = 0. Is my code correct?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the carousel slider to show all `broadcasters` from every item of `liveResult`?

Comment: yes, to show all broadcasters from every item of liveResult

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in the code:

1. `itemBuilder` will build the carousel slider items based on the `itemCount`, so you don't need to loop over `broadcasterLength` inside the builder.
2. Inside the second loop (the one that iterates over `k`), you're returning a widget, which will cause the for loop to break and return the widget based on the condition when `i` equals to 0 and `k` equals to 0. This will make all items in the carousel slider be that same widget.

---

To build the items that will show all items from `broadcasters` from every item in `liveResult`, you need to flatten the list by using [collection for](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators) and [spread operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators):

```dart
final allBroadcasters = [for (final result in liveResult) ...result.broadcasters];
```

Now you can use it in the `CarouselSlider` like this:

```dart
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: allBroadcasters.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int pageViewIndex) {
    final broadcaster = allBroadcasters[index];
    return InkWell(
      // ...
    );
  },
)
```